# It is possible to remove the Shadow of the Icons (items) on a googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps, drawable

I have a Google map with these kind of items on it:

```
drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trazeicon);
```

but automatically, Android draws a shadow of the image `trazeicon` on the map, and I don't want to have that shadow.

How can I remove it?

#### EDIT:

I got the error: `Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

Here is the full code:

```
package com.GPSLoc;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;
    
    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }
    
    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }
    
    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
          //super(defaultMarker);
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
          mContext = context;
    }
    public void clear()
    {
        mOverlays.clear();
    }
    
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
    }
    
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        if(!shadow)
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to override the `draw()` method when you extend ItemizedOverlay.  Like this:

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        if(!shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: where i have to override it? on the activity? i only want to be without shadow these icon, not all the icons

Comment: No, on the `ItemizedOverlay`.

Comment: i got error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody....... i dedited first post with my code of itemizedoverlay, read it plz

Comment: it seems that some ; or { is missing but it isn't, i search on all the code and all is ok... maybe something is wrong in your code?

Comment: That's weird, I got the same thing when I pasted that code in, but when I used the Eclipse Source Override function and typed it in it worked.  I have no idea why.