# Displaying icons properly on mapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am building an android mapView application, and I use icons to mark certain places on the map. For some reason, the icons are displayed with a black "shadow" around them. How can I fix this?

http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/4695/capturexgy.jpg

Thanks ahead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327733/it-is-possible-to-remove-the-shadow-of-the-icons-items-on-a-googlemap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ItemizedOverlay, try overriding the onDraw method and passing in false for shadow e.g.

```
@Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, false, when);
    }
```